# Trouble installing a python package with conda

Tags: python-2.7, conda

I'm trying to install a Python package (Pyclone) using anaconda (the latest release of miniconda, specifically) using the following suggested script:

```
conda install pyclone -c aroth85
```

And I get the following error:

> Package missing in current win-64 channels

I'm not sure what exactly this means; Is it that the package is not being maintained?

I should note that when I tried putting the -c after install:

```
conda install -c pyclone aroth85
```

Because I saw that order used for other package, I got the following warning as well:

> WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
>       requested channel with url: https://conda.anaconda.org/pyclone
>       It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
>       your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.
>       If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that 
>       the
>       channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
>       `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
>       `$ mkdir noarch`
>       `$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json`
>       `$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json`

In addition to the original error about the package missing in current win-64 channels.

Does anyone know what the problem is here? Or do I need to contact package's maintainers if it's something wrong on their end?

By the way, the package's creators' installation instructions are [here](https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pyclone/wiki/Installation#markdown-header-easy-installation)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here that there is not a version of that package available for `win-64`, only `linux-64` and `osx-64`: https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyclone

This means that the owner of the `aroth85` channel does not maintain a package for Windows 64 bit. <s>So, you'll have to go for the manual installation, which may or may not be a difficult task. The instructions are here: https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pyclone/wiki/Installation#markdown-header-manual-installation</s> According to the [Tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pyclone/wiki/Tutorial), the author of the package has no intention of supporting Windows:

> It almost certainly will not work for Windows and there will likely never be support in PyClone for Windows

Finally, regarding that warning - the `-c` or `--channel` option adds a channel for conda to search for the package. The name of the channel is the word that appears immediately after the flag, regardless of where the flag is located. Thus, the first command

```
conda install pyclone -c aroth85
```

looks in the `aroth85` channel for a package called `pyclone` (and can't find the package, because it doesn't exist, as we saw at the link to anaconda.org). This command is equivalent to

```
conda install -c aroth85 pyclone
```

The second command

```
conda install -c pyclone aroth85
```

looks in the `pyclone` channel for a package called `aroth85`. The warning message means that conda cannot find a channel called `pyclone`, because no such channel exists. Then (I would guess) the error message states that conda cannot find a package called `aroth85`, again, because no such package exists.

Comment: When I manually install PyClone, the PyClone command isn't recognized in Anaconda; this is an issue because the package was apparently made to be used via Anaconda.

Comment: From the [Tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pyclone/wiki/Tutorial): "It almost certainly will not work for Windows and there will likely never be support in PyClone for Windows."

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're using Windows, based on that error message. It looks like there isn't a Windows version of that package in the conda win-64 channels. This is something you could possibly try and raise with the package author, but if you just want to get the package working, I would suggest you try a manual install.

The details for doing a manual install are all given in the install instructions you linked to.

Comment: When I install pyclone manually (from the Anaconda prompt) it seems to install successfully but still doesn't recognize the PyClone command.